# not able to access this JSON NESTED OBJECT

Tags: json, firebase, angular7

I've been trying to access this nested json object which is a response from firebase. I'm using angular 7 on the frontend, and I want to display this data on page.

Returned data:

```
{"-LZn4rzsI3_0Mm0pcUZ2":{"email":"primedine@gmail.com","name":"Prime 
Dine Restaurant","phone":9512556799},"-LZn4vGB7v0frlDywQ1x": 
{"email":"mango@gmail.com","name":"@Mango","phone":7992556799},"- 
LZn4xyGeo-yh6945mKC":{"email":"desitadka@gmail.com","name":"Global 
Desi Tadka","phone":8872556799},"-LZn50DSU3JNw6hNcdzz": 
{"email":"vishala@gmail.com","name":"VIshala","phone":9972556799}}
```

So far, I've tried accessing by putting the response in a variable and then using data[0][name], but it doesn't work. I also tried accessing it by just the key(name here), but that too didn't work. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), as follows:

```
var json = '{"-LZn4rzsI3_0Mm0pcUZ2":{"email":"primedine@gmail.com","name":"Prime 
Dine Restaurant","phone":9512556799},"-LZn4vGB7v0frlDywQ1x": 
{"email":"mango@gmail.com","name":"@Mango","phone":7992556799},"- 
LZn4xyGeo-yh6945mKC":{"email":"desitadka@gmail.com","name":"Global 
Desi Tadka","phone":8872556799},"-LZn50DSU3JNw6hNcdzz": 
{"email":"vishala@gmail.com","name":"VIshala","phone":9972556799}}';
var obj = JSON.parse(json);

//Use the object as desired, for example:
Object.keys(obj).forEach(e =>
  console.log(`key = ${e}  name = ${obj[e].name}`)
);
```